# How to make apple watch grid using html and css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make apple watch apps grid using html and css and also want to animate it. What is the best way to make this.

I have managed to make this by setting the position to absolute and then used properties like top,left etc. to position them on required position.

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 280px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clock {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: resize 15s ease;
}

.sm {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.music {
  top: -100%;
  left: -50%;
  background: #fb0091;
}

.message {
  top: -100%;
  right: -50%;
  background: #1089ff;
}

.stopwatch {
  top: 50%;
  left: -100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #f75f00;
}

.health {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: -50%;
  background: red;
}

.whatsapp {
  bottom: -100%;
  right: -50%;
  background: darkgreen;
}

.web {
  top: 50%;
  right: -100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sm calender"></div>
  <div class="clock" id="clock">
    <div class="sm music">
      <div class="s map"></div>
      <div class="s weather"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sm message">
      <div class="s phone"></div>
      <div class="s camera"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sm stopwatch"></div>
    <div class="sm whatsapp">
      <div class="s videos"></div>
      <div class="s files"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sm health">
      <div class="s run"></div>
      <div class="s  setting"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sm web"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sm photos"></div>
</div>
```

I have not pasted the full css file this is just so you understand how I am doing it currently.

I expect the output to have icons arrangemet like we get in apple watch.